# How do I hide a notification, when a button is clicked and if a previously presented notification is still visible

Tags: ios, push-notification

The code below works as follows:
If a "Like" button is pressed a pop up notification is displayed while the app is in the foreground

```
func ButtonPressed(index: Int, buttonName: String) {
    
    print(buttonName)
    
    if buttonName == "DisLike" {
        guard let indexPath = CardsCollection.indexPathsForVisibleItems.first.flatMap({
            IndexPath(item: index + 1, section: $0.section)
        }), CardsCollection.cellForItem(at: indexPath) != nil else {

            return

        }
        CardsCollection.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .left, animated: true)
    }
    
    else {
        showLocalNotification()
        
    }
}
```

When the "dislike" button is pressed I want to hide any previous notifications that are still displayed because its default expiry time has not yet occurred.

Here’s the showNotification function

func showLocalNotification() {

```
    // create notification content
    
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "Image Got Liked!"
        content.body = "Awsome You Like An Image!"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
    // triger the notification
    
    let triger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false)

    // make a request for notification
        
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Homyt", content: content, trigger: triger)
        
    // make the request
        
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code in the showLocalNotification()? To be able to dismiss the notification, it would help to see how it is created and displayed.

Comment: Here is the code

Comment: func showLocalNotification() {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Image Got Liked!"
            content.body = "Awsome You Like An Image!"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        // triger the notification
        
        let triger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Homyt", content: content, trigger: triger)    
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)        
    }